# I ran into this issue with adding babeljs to my react project. any pointers?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I ran the command `npm install babel-preset-es2015 -g` and also `npm install -g babel@5` since it was giving me a list of errors when I installed locally with the `--save`flag

```
     {
  "name": "reactintro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Osama Said",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

this is what appears in my package file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do ? `npm install babel-preset-es2015 -g --save` ?

Comment: Shouldn't it appear in my dependencies?

Comment: you need to add `--save` and it will

Comment: i did an answer, plz accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a dependencies in a package.json, you have to add `--save`.
When you install it globally with `-g`, in fact you installed it in the main node folder on your computer.

see more on [npm install doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot.